# append brackets to all constants beginning with L:: where it not exist on end

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I have many PHP Files where I need to add on end "()" to every constant beginning with "L::" which don't have on end "(". It should by applied to all *.php including subfolders) :

```
L::WHAT_EVER
<?=L::WHAT_EVER?>
```

should become:

```
L::WHAT_EVER()
<?=L::WHAT_EVER()?>
```

but not touch any of them:

```
L::WHAT_EVER()
L::WHAT_EVER('aaa')
L::WHAT_EVER($a, $b)
```

Is there any sed regex command that I could apply to reach this Goal?

Comment: yes there is ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier with `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\bL::\w++\K(?!\()/()/g' ./*.php
```

- `\bL::`: `L::` following  a word boundary  (to avoid replacing `NIL::Foo` ones).
- `\w`: any word character (ASCII letters, numbers or underscore)
- `++`: one or more (of the `\w`s), but don't backtrack
- `\K`: set the start of the matched portion (so just after that word)
- `(?!...)`: negative look ahead assertion. So here only matches if what follows is not a `(`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl and the better regex engine is easier as it has lookaround feature, for GNU sed testing:

```
sed -E 's/(\w+::\w+)([^(].+)?/\1()\2/' ./*.php
```

solving recursive glob process:

```
find . -iname '*.php' -exec sed -E 's/(\w+::\w+)([^(].+)?/\1()\2/' '{}' +
```

for its real editing, add -i option,

```
find . -iname '*.php' -exec sed -i -E 's/(\w+::\w+)([^(].+)?/\1()\2/' '{}' +
```